# How to change the workspace navigation keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I wanted to change my workspace navigation.

```
move to workspace left -> alt+A
move to workspace right -> alt+D
move to workspace above -> alt+W
move to workspace below -> alt+S
```

Everything was fine except for alt+A because when I press alt+A I get to access the All Settings above. It changes the page to all settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use compizconfig-settings-manager (ccsm). The package to install this is calles compizconfig-settings-manager and in software center it can be found on compiz' details page.
In ccsm edit the settings for the "Desktop Wall". There you can adjust the keybindings you want to modify.

Comment: Finally an answer that works!

Comment: Saved my eclipse coding day :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2321968/1422630